# can't use tip on d3 v5 on typescript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

i have this code:

```
 var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .attr('id', 'tooltip')
      .html(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .direction('n')
      .offset([-10, 0]);
```

i am getting this error:

> property tip does not exist on type @types/d3/index

I tried this without success:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Tip from "d3-tip";
(d3 as any).tip = d3Tip;
```

how do i make this work?

Comment: Why are you trying to merge two libraries?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import * as d3Tip from "d3-tip";

var tip = d3Tip.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .attr('id', 'tooltip')
      .html(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .direction('n')
      .offset([-10, 0]);
```